# On deploying 2 triggers in same org, it fails with 'System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 ', but on deploying either of the one it works

Tags: trigger, deployment

## trigger 1

```
trigger Order_AIUD_part1 on Order (after insert, after update, after delete) 
{Map<Id, List<Order>> acctIdOpptyListMap = new Map<Id, List<Order>>();
    Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Order> opptyList = new List<Order>();
    if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isInsert){
        for(Order oppty : trigger.New){
            if(oppty.AccountId != null){
                acctIds.add(oppty.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(trigger.isDelete){
        for(Order oppty : trigger.old){
            if(oppty.AccountId != null){
                acctIds.add(oppty.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(acctIds.size() > 0){
        opptyList = [SELECT  X18x181__c, AccountId FROM Order WHERE AccountId IN : acctIds];
        for(Order oppty : opptyList){
            if(!acctIdOpptyListMap.containsKey(oppty.AccountId)){
                acctIdOpptyListMap.put(oppty.AccountId, new List<Order>());
            }
            acctIdOpptyListMap.get(oppty.AccountId).add(oppty); 
        }   
        List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
        acctList = [SELECT x18x18s__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: acctIds];
        for(Account acct : acctList){
            List<Order> tempOpptyList = new List<Order>();
            tempOpptyList = acctIdOpptyListMap.get(acct.Id);
            Double totalOpptyX18x181 = 0;
            for(Order oppty : tempOpptyList){
                if(oppty.X18x181__c != null){
                    totalOpptyX18x181 += oppty.X18x181__c;
                }
            }
            acct.x18x18s__c = totalOpptyX18x181;
        }
        update acctList;
    }
    Map<Id, List<Order>> acct1Idoppty1List1Map1 = new Map<Id, List<Order>>();
    Set<Id> acct1Ids1 = new Set<Id>();
    List<Order> oppty1List1 = new List<Order>();
    if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isInsert){
        for(Order oppty1 : trigger.New){
            if(oppty1.AccountId != null){
                acct1Ids1.add(oppty1.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(trigger.isDelete){
        for(Order oppty1 : trigger.old){
            if(oppty1.AccountId != null){
                acct1Ids1.add(oppty1.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(acct1Ids1.size() > 0){
        oppty1List1 = [SELECT  X18x18_Black1__c, AccountId FROM Order WHERE AccountId IN : acct1Ids1];
        for(Order oppty1 : oppty1List1){
            if(!acct1Idoppty1List1Map1.containsKey(oppty1.AccountId)){
                acct1Idoppty1List1Map1.put(oppty1.AccountId, new List<Order>());
            }
            acct1Idoppty1List1Map1.get(oppty1.AccountId).add(oppty1); 
        }   
        List<Account> acct1List1 = new List<Account>();
        acct1List1 = [SELECT x18x18bs__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: acct1Ids1];
        for(Account acct1 : acct1List1){
            List<Order> tempoppty1List1 = new List<Order>();
            tempoppty1List1 = acct1Idoppty1List1Map1.get(acct1.Id);
            Double totaloppty1X18x181 = 0;
            for(Order oppty1 : tempoppty1List1){
                if(oppty1.X18x18_Black1__c != null){
                    totaloppty1X18x181 += oppty1.X18x18_Black1__c;
                }
            }
            acct1.x18x18bs__c = totaloppty1X18x181;
        }
        update acct1List1;
    }
    Map<Id, List<Order>> acct2Idoppty2List2Map2 = new Map<Id, List<Order>>();
    Set<Id> acct2Ids2 = new Set<Id>();
    List<Order> oppty2List2 = new List<Order>();
    if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isInsert){
        for(Order oppty2 : trigger.New){
            if(oppty2.AccountId != null){
                acct2Ids2.add(oppty2.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(trigger.isDelete){
        for(Order oppty2 : trigger.old){
            if(oppty2.AccountId != null){
                acct2Ids2.add(oppty2.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(acct2Ids2.size() > 0){
        oppty2List2 = [SELECT  X18x18_Quilted1__c, AccountId FROM Order WHERE AccountId IN : acct2Ids2];
        for(Order oppty2 : oppty2List2){
            if(!acct2Idoppty2List2Map2.containsKey(oppty2.AccountId)){
                acct2Idoppty2List2Map2.put(oppty2.AccountId, new List<Order>());
            }
            acct2Idoppty2List2Map2.get(oppty2.AccountId).add(oppty2); 
        }   
        List<Account> acct2List2 = new List<Account>();
        acct2List2 = [SELECT X18x18qs__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: acct2Ids2];
        for(Account acct2 : acct2List2){
            List<Order> tempoppty2List2 = new List<Order>();
            tempoppty2List2 = acct2Idoppty2List2Map2.get(acct2.Id);
            Double totaloppty2X18x181 = 0;
            for(Order oppty2 : tempoppty2List2){
                if(oppty2.X18x18_Quilted1__c != null){
                    totaloppty2X18x181 += oppty2.X18x18_Quilted1__c;
                }
            }
            acct2.X18x18qs__c = totaloppty2X18x181;
        }
        update acct2List2;
    }


 Map<Id, List<Order>> acctIdoppty3List3Map3 = new Map<Id, List<Order>>();
    Set<Id> acctIds3 = new Set<Id>();
    List<Order> oppty3List3 = new List<Order>();
    if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isInsert){
        for(Order oppty3 : trigger.New){
            if(oppty3.AccountId != null){
                acctIds3.add(oppty3.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(trigger.isDelete){
        for(Order oppty3 : trigger.old){
            if(oppty3.AccountId != null){
                acctIds3.add(oppty3.AccountId);
            }
        }    
    }
    if(acctIds3.size() > 0){
        oppty3List3 = [SELECT  X15x15_White_Wipers1__c, AccountId FROM Order WHERE AccountId IN : acctIds3];
        for(Order oppty3 : oppty3List3){
            if(!acctIdoppty3List3Map3.containsKey(oppty3.AccountId)){
                acctIdoppty3List3Map3.put(oppty3.AccountId, new List<Order>());
            }
            acctIdoppty3List3Map3.get(oppty3.AccountId).add(oppty3); 
        }   
        List<Account> acctList3 = new List<Account>();
        acctList3 = [SELECT White_wipers_s__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: acctIds3];
        for(Account acct : acctList3){
            List<Order> tempoppty3List3 = new List<Order>();
            tempoppty3List3 = acctIdoppty3List3Map3.get(acct.Id);
            Double totaloppty3X18x181 = 0;
            for(Order oppty3 : tempoppty3List3){
                if(oppty3.X15x15_White_Wipers1__c != null){
                    totaloppty3X18x181 += oppty3.X15x15_White_Wipers1__c;
                }
            }
            acct.White_wipers_s__c = totaloppty3X18x181;
        }
        update acctList3;
    }
    }
```

## trigger 2

```
trigger theorderz  on Run__c (after insert, after update) {
    List<order> ordtoinsert = new list<order>();
    for(Run__c o: Trigger.new){
        if(o.Color__c=='Orange'){
            if(o.Week_Cycle__c =='Week 1' ){
                List<Account> toinsert = [Select id, Name from Account where run__c ='Orange' AND (Wk1__c = TRUE) ]; // 3DRobotics
                for(Account ordertocreate: toinsert){
                    order orderObj =new order();
                    orderObj.Accountid=ordertocreate.Id;
                    orderObj.EffectiveDate=date.today();
                    orderObj.Status='Draft';    
                    orderObj.run__c=o.id;           
                    ordtoinsert.add(orderObj);
                }
                upsert ordtoinsert Account.id;
                system.debug('---->'+toinsert);



}
        else if(o.Week_Cycle__c == 'Week 2' ){
            List<Account> toinsert = [Select id, Name from Account where run__c = 'Orange' AND (Wk2__c = True)]; // ABB
            for(Account ordertocreate: toinsert){
                order orderObj =new order();
                orderObj.Accountid=ordertocreate.Id;
                orderObj.EffectiveDate=date.today();
                orderObj.Status='Draft';  
                orderObj.run__c=o.id;              
                ordtoinsert.add(orderObj);
            }
            upsert ordtoinsert Account.id;
            system.debug('---->'+toinsert);

        }
        else if(o.Week_Cycle__c == 'Week 3' ){
            List<Account> toinsert = [Select id, Name from Account where run__c = 'Orange' AND (Wk3__c = True)]; // Adept
            for(Account ordertocreate: toinsert){
                order orderObj =new order();
                orderObj.Accountid=ordertocreate.Id;
                orderObj.EffectiveDate=date.today();
                orderObj.Status='Draft';  
                orderObj.run__c=o.id;              
                ordtoinsert.add(orderObj);
            }
            upsert ordtoinsert Account.id;
            system.debug('---->'+toinsert);

        }
```

Comment: This means your trigger is hitting governor limit.Maximum 100 SOQL query that can be run in your context.Avoid putiing queries inside for loop.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is in Trigger 2.  You are doing a query inside of a loop at 3 different places.  Pull the query outside of the loop using a Map if you have to:

```
for(Run__c o: Trigger.new){
        if(o.Color__c=='Orange'){
            if(o.Week_Cycle__c =='Week 1' ){
                **List<Account> toinsert = [Select id, Name from Account where run__c ='Orange' AND (Wk1__c = TRUE) ]; // 3DRobotics**
                for(Account ordertocreate: toinsert){
```

Comment: To add on to dphil, try and practice proper coding techniques.  Here is a good place to start https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code